# EntityFramework code-first - right place for entity "import" function

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an EF-driven Repository pattern implementation. Roughly looks like this:

```
public class DataRepository : IDataRepository
{
  public IDbSet<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to implement a Contact import functionality, which has some custom logic for manipulating the entity which is being imported (i.e. it is different from Adding an entity to the repo).

I see two options right now:

1. Implement an extension method on the `IDbSet<Contacts> Contacts`, which would allow me to do:

   `dataRepository.Contacts.Import(contact);`

   `dataRepository.Save();`
2. Implement a static method on the `Contact` class, which will then allow me to do something like:

   `Contact.Import(contact);`

   but then I am not sure how I would attach the entity to the context, without breaking my abstraction...

I could also implement an 'Import Service' which wraps this functionality, but it seems very old-school. e.g.:

```
public class ContactsImportService
{
  public ContactsImportService(IDataRepository dataRepo)
  {
    ...
  }

  public void Import(Contact contact)
  {
    // Manipulate contact here
    this.dataRepo.Add(contact);
    this.dataRepo.Save();
  }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes without a single explanation why. Typical StackExchange.

Comment: This is the wrong forum for this kind of questions. You need to present  working code if you wish a review. _I was just writing this comment to support my downvote but you were quicker ;-P_

Comment: I have presented three different versions of a working code. I won't write a complete implementation here of any of them, it's not necessary. And what is the correct forum?

Comment: "Thanks for the downvotes without a single explanation why. Typical StackExchange" well I didn't downvote, but its typical for StackExchange that users won't read the help center of the site they are going to ask.

Comment: The [on-topic](/help/on-topic) and [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask] pages should give you a better idea of the kind of questions we're looking for, and how to formulate them well to make the most out of this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing an extension method will be a good approach.

However, since you already have a repository layer with `IDataRepository` & an implementation class `DataRepository`, the best approach will be to declare a method signature in `IDataRepository` interface & implement the method in `DataRepository` class itself.

This will ensure, we are not touching/extending the direct data access objects of entity framework that is `IDbSet<Contact>`.

Also its always good thing to group the methods working on object sets (aka Add, edit, delete) in a single place like `DataRepository` (Since you already have this in place).

The import operation as you have specified is specifically for a single entity & I hope its carrying all relevant information for the import within the Contact object itself.